# ActiveJob + Sidekiq 6.0.3: How to write to a log file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I'm using Sidekiq to get some background jobs done. I am also trying to log some messages from these jobs to a log file, but I have been unable to do this simple task.

Example of the kind of job I'm running

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform
    text = 'Print me to a file!'
    Rails.logger.error "Rails.logger.info : #{text}"
    logger.error "logger.info : #{text}"
  end
end
```

Running `TestJob.perform_now`, in a controller action for example, works as expected, printing the messages to the server terminal output, as well as to `logs/development.log`.

But running `TestJob.perform_later` doesn't print my messages. Anywhere. Not to the Sidekiq terminal, the server terminal, log files, nothing.

I tried redirecting the logs, as suggested in the [Sidekiq Logging wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Logging#api-changes). But the messages didn't get printed there either.

I feel like I might be missing something crucial.

Comment: If Sidekiq is running and is picking up your job `log/sidekiq.log` will have `start` and `done` entries for `TestJob`.  Are there any errors there?

Comment: @cschroed nope...

Comment: If the job is running then you could put this at the top of your `perform` method: `raise Rails.logger.inspect`.  Then in the Sidekiq Dead Job queue you'll see more info about what the log level is and where it's sending its output.

Answer (score 3):

Try to call `Sidekiq.logger`, as in:

```rb
    Sidekiq.logger.error "logger.info : #{text}"
```

Putting "logger.info" in the log of an error might be a little weird, but I was just taking from the example posted in the question.